# How to use logic path in web site

Tags: html, web

I have a website:

```
www.mydomain.com/panel/abcde.html
```

I don't remember the difference between `./` and `../`
`./` is used to return in the first level?
Instead `../` is used to simulate all domain?
`.../` exists?

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/153165/what-does-represent-while-giving-path

Answer (score 0):

I believe it is like this :

> /  = root of the currently location
>
> ./ = current directory
>
> ../ = parent of current directory

Answer (score 0):

Reference could be found [here](https://superuser.com/questions/153165/what-does-represent-while-giving-path)

- `/` is the root folder of the filesystem.
- `./` usually denotes the current folder that your program or script is in, usually the same one with the file you run.
- `../` denotes the folder above the current one.
- `.../` Does not exist. If you type that on terminal, it will throw error `No such file or directory`

Comment: ../ is the highest level? does .../ exist?

Comment: No. It does not. You can try them in your computer terminal. If you type `cd .../` it will throw error `No such file or directory`